# UnknownTimeZoneError when using RequestContext

Tags: python, django, pytz

When using Django 1.4, I am getting an `UnknownTimeZoneError` for `America/Chicago` when using RequestContext, but it works without it...any ideas?

**Error Message**

```
UnknownTimeZoneError at /my_proj/bad_view/
'America/Chicago'
```

**Source**

```
# This works
def good_view(request):
    data = {}
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html',
                              data)

# This doesn't
def bad_view(request):
    data = {}
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html',
                              data,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about timezone support you should add `USE_TZ = False` to your `settings.py`.

If you want timezone support you should install `pytz`:

```
pip install pytz
```

I believe the error is caused by django getting `America/Chicago` in the template from the request, but django's limited timezone data doesn't have this timezone. The error will go away if `pytz` is installed.

You should read [django's timezone docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones) to learn how django 1.4 handles timezones.

Comment: Slight variation...I had to upgrade pytz via `pip install pytz --upgrade`  Thanks!