# How to configure default timezone in Settings.py to Singapore

Tags: django, timezone

I am trying to configure the default timezone in settings.py to 'Asia/Singapore'

however after I do that the page doesn't load and I get sent to the error page.

Currently I am dealing with it by setting the TIME_ZONE to None

[image]

[image]

misc : I have the python pytz downloaded

I want to display the server time (+8 GMT Singapore time on the website)

Comment: `Asia/Singapore` is listed in [avalaible time_zone choices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE)! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254409/unknowntimezoneerror-when-using-requestcontext

Comment: Double check that pytz is running: run `from pytz import timezone` `eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')` from django shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). If you have setuptools installed, it is as easy as running `easy_install --upgrade pytz`

I am running Python 2.7.3 with pytz installed and I can set the timezone to  `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Singapore'` without issues.

Comment: OP says that has pytz downloaded and you can see it in error trace python path. Wait for comments OP response.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your version of django and pytz. Everything is working. Then I've tried some other version of django and pytz. It was working fine too. So I found only two ideas about that problem:

1) Maybe it's about a method of typing 'Asia/Singapore' . Does your keyboard have two ways of typing some symbols, like a? So you see, my name is 'Павел Тявин', and it has a cyrillic letter 'а' which is very similar to the latin 'a' but can make a difference to python

2) Maybe your ../pytz/zoneinfo directory doesn't have right to see from django? You can change user right with the `chmod` command

Comment: hello thank you for your reply. can you expand on the 2nd point?

Comment: I was talking about permission block. You can change them by [chmod] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command